# jqGrid custom edit form

Tags: jqgrid, popup, modal-dialog

I'm trying to implement a modal popup custom form such as the one shown in http://nanet.website/test/samples/dlgModal.html for editing data in a jqGrid such as the one shown in http://nanet.website/test/samples/jqGrid.html
Anyone skilled for help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correct the question you try to create a custom form edit in jqGrid using Booostrap.

Example of custom form edit can be found in Guriddo Knowledge base [here](http://guriddo.net/?kbe_knowledgebase=using-templates-in-form-editing)

For Bootstrap UI just point the grid to use a Bootstrap as described [here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/#using-bootstrap-css-framework)